# Can I ask original poster to not accept my answer in order for it to potentially receive more answers?

Tags: discussion

I gave an answer to the following question

> ***[PyTorch's `torch.as_strided` with negative strides for making a Toeplitz matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896578/pytorchs-torch-as-strided-with-negative-strides-for-making-a-toeplitz-matrix)***

which I did not initially have the answer to. However, since I was so intrigued by the problem I ended up spending some time figuring it out and writing down a proper answer. This was only four hours after OP had posted the question (tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scipy), and [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch)).

I would have wished for other users to post their answers and get feedback on mine. Since I had written a rather long answer. What instead happened is after a few hours after answering it got accepted straight away. Note, I did not receive any feedback from OP on the answer or validation/remarks from other users. For me, this means two things:

- the OP was content with the answer I gave and they believed it solve their problem. There were three sub-questions included in the post, I gave an answer to all three.
- This question will now leave the unanswered/active question list and venture into the abyss of old forgotten questions.

---

The question is pretty niche since it looks at solving a PyTorch implementation problem. However, it raises multiple underlying issues. Consequently, the ideas I present in my answer touch upon multiple different aspects. They essentially come down to:

- **How do negative strides work in NumPy?**. I do not explain how negative strides work I only go through the given SciPy source code snippet and *describe* the usage of negative strides.
- **If it is possible to implement such a method in PyTorch?**
- **How to construct a Toeplitz matrix, and make the operation differentiable?**. Make it possible to call a backward pass on the resulting tensor.

Usually, based on the question I can gauge the interest of the OP balance my commitment to answering the question. In this instance, I was particularly interested and wanted to give more than a quick answer, which I did.

Right now, what it feels like, is: I would have gotten the same response if I had provided a 6-line long answer.

*In the end, maybe OP was just looking for a quick Toeplitz implementation in PyTorch, came upon the Scipy's implementation in NumPy, tried to replicate it in PyTorch, failed because it doesn't support this feature, asked on SO, got an answer, copied the five lines of code, left... that I don't know.*

---

Would this question get more views/interactions/answers had the answer not been accepted that quickly? I believe so.

Could I ask the original poster to *unaccept* it? If so, do you think that would give it a chance to receive additional answers or interactions? I do understand having a question with one long answer does not exactly encourage a user to come up with another answer. Did I simply respond too soon to the answer, preventing it from seeing other answers?

Comment: You could start a bounty to attract more answers.

Comment: You can ask the OP anything. It's up to them what to do. Maybe better to spend some rep in a bounty, if you are really interested in additional answers.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov *there will be no new answers and the only one can be safely accepted*, that's pretty much opposite to what I would like to achieve!

Comment: This looks like a pretty clear case of "needs more focus" (as has been mentioned). I doubt the issue is *how* you responded – the issue is *what* you responded *to*. The current state is probably the best case for you; drawing more attention to it is not likely to improve the situation.

Comment: You can ask the OP to dance the Macarena. Doesn't mean they will.